# SVD methods for minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, minimal-polynomials

This question is a reference request, or even if anyone can enlighten on the subject of SVD(singular Value Decomposition) methods for sequence extrapolation. On the subject of minimal polynomials of a matrix, can one use SVD methods for computing the minimal polynomial. SVD methods can be used in sequence transformation, but are there any SVD algorithms that can either approximate, or even give minimal polynomial of a matrix. For instance, one could consider the the adjacency matrix of a graph, and we needed a SVD algorithm for computing its minimal polynomial(even its approximation). Any references to such methods, or even ways to extrapolate the polynomial, using SVD, are existing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that an explanation of continuation by fast Krylov subspace Eigen-decomposition methods together with references to the original publications was in some introduction or appendix at least in the published book of https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~bilbao/master/goodcopy.html. I couldn't find it again at the moment, but why should I care?

Comment: thanks, for reference, but as a side note, Krylov subspace decomposition Eigen decomposition, is a start point to the problem of sequence decomposition, using SVD?

Comment: It's not really a start point with respect to SVD. There is a close connection between Krylov subspace methods and minimal polynomials. It wasn't even a SVD, but just a general Eigen-decomposition. It should be clear how to get the minimal polynomial of a square matrix from its Eigen-decomposition. But they do use it for sequence extrapolation of transient (linear response) behavior when resonances are present, which could otherwise become annoying.